# direct sum of $T$-invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:V \rightarrow V $ be a linear transformation. 
For $v \in V$ I construct the $I(v)=\mathrm{span} \{v,Tv,...T^{k-1}v\}$.

If $\mathrm{dim} (I(v)) < \mathrm{dim}V$, I can choose a $u$ which does not  belong to $I(v)$ and similarly I take $I(u)$.
Keep going like that i want to prove that at the end I will have created a basis for $V$.

IS it true that $I(u)$ won't have any common element with $I(v)$?

Comment: Welcome to the site. In order to make your question more readable I suggest you check out the following https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to learn the basics on how to type math on the site. Instead of writing T: V -> V, write $T : V \rightarrow V.$

Answer (score 1):

It is not true. Consider
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0&0&0\\1&0&1\\0&0&0\end{array}\right).
$$ For a standard basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$, it holds $I(e_1)=\text{span}\{e_1,e_2\}$ and $I(e_3)=\text{span}\{e_2,e_3\}$. Hence $I(e_1)\cap I(e_3)\neq\varnothing.$